# Form not printing anything

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've tried my best to replicate the files for the user to see a message displayed when information is typed into the user and password text boxes. However, the message display is not happening.

Here is my ajax.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var sendu = $("#username").val();
        var sendp = $("#pw").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "username="+sendu+"&password="+sendp,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg, string, jqXHR){
                    $("#result").html(msg+string+jqXHR);
                }
            });

    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
<input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" /><p>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
<p><div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my ajax.php file:

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST["username"];
$pw = $_REQUEST["pw"];

$list = array('name'=>$name, 'password'=>$pw);

$c = json_encode($list);

echo $c;

?>
```

Comment: so what is displayed in `#result`

Comment: @lbu: shouldn't be anything until a message is sent there in the ajax call. At least that's what I believe.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#result").html(msg.name + msg.password);
```

etc.

Change

```
$pw = $_REQUEST["pw"];
```

to

```
$pw = $_REQUEST["password"];
```

You are sending variables with ajax... and you have assigned to variable to be password, not pw (which is the name of your input).

And don't forget to actually write something inside the inputs so you can receive something back also.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you even have something inside your inputs to test with? Check your browser javascript debugging console if you can see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        var sendu = $("#username").val(),
            sendp = $("#pw").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {username : sendu, password : sendp},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                 $("#result").html(data.name).prepend(data.password);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["username"];
    $pw = $_POST["password"];
    $list = array('name'=>$name, 'password'=>$pw);

    echo json_encode($list);
?>
```

Comment: Still having no luck with your suggested adjustments.